# Send Email URL button (List Button)

Tags: custom-button, urlhacking, url

I created a URL button to send an email which works fine in partner portal but not in standard salesforce.I need to remove first extra slash(/) for standard salesforce.How to do this

[image]

**Update**
 When I updated the code according to @Ray Dehler I am getting an error on partner portal but works good in standard  salesforce.Below find the screen shot of url of both partner portal and standard salesforce

[image]

[image]

```
/{!IF(CONTAINS($Profile.Name, "Title"),'partners','')}/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?  p2_lkid={!Lead.Id}&rtype=00Q&retURL={!IF(CONTAINS($Profile.Name, "Title"),  URLENCODE('partners')&'/' & URLENCODE(Lead.Id) ,URLENCODE(Lead.Id))}&template_id={!IF(CONTAINS($Profile.Name, "Title"), '','00Xc0000000MNDM')}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the button behavior as Execute Javascript and content as On Click Javascript and updated the below code and it worked.

```
var url = ''; 

if({!CONTAINS($Profile.Name, 'Title')}){ 
url += '/partners'; 
} 

url += 
'/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?' + 
'p2_lkid={!Lead.Id}&rtype=00Q&retURL='; 

 if({!CONTAINS($Profile.Name, 'Title')}){ 
 url += '/partners'; 
 } 

url += 
'/{!Lead.Id}' + 
'&template_id='; 

if({!NOT(CONTAINS($Profile.Name, 'Title'))}){ 
 url += '00Xc0000000MNDM'; 
} 

location.replace(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as this:

```
{!IF(CONTAINS($Profile.Name, "Title"),'/partners','')}/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?  p2_lkid={!Lead.Id}&rtype=00Q&retURL={!IF(CONTAINS($Profile.Name, "Title"),  URLENCODE('partners')&'/' & URLENCODE(Lead.Id) ,URLENCODE(Lead.Id))}&template_id={!IF(CONTAINS($Profile.Name, "Title"), '','00Xc0000000MNDM')}
```

I moved the / inside the IF statement.

Comment: I updated with your code and it stopped working for partner portal but now it works for standard salesforce

Comment: What are each of the rendered URLs?

Comment: .Updated with screenshots

Comment: And what is the URL that works from the partner portal?

Comment: /partners/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid=00Qa000001HGcJn&rtype=00Q&retURL=partners%2F00Qa000001HGcJn&template_id=